# C# - pass the user id from selected grid view column to another page using session variables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am going to pass the selected user id in PMUserList.aspx and pass it to the UserEdit.aspx. The grid view table data is from MySQL.
For example, I want to edit user with id: '15001'. Then I hit the 'Edit' button which in the same row. I hope to pass the '15001' to the UserEdit.aspx

[outcome1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE06h.png)

expected outcome:
[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oquCt.png)

*Database structure:* user_id is a string.

*PMUserList.aspx*

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gvUserList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" SelectedIndex="0" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="User ID" SortExpression="id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="contact_no" HeaderText="Contact no" SortExpression="Contact" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="role" HeaderText="Role" SortExpression="Role" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnEdit"
                                    runat="server"
                                    Text="Edit"
                                    ForeColor="Black"
                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("user_id") %>'
                                    OnCommand="BtnEdit_Command"
                                    OnClientClick='<%# "javascript:return confirm(\"Edit [" + Eval("user_id") + "]\");"  %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
```

*PMUserList.aspx.cs*

```
   protected void BtnEdit_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["userid"] = String.Format("PMUserList?user_id={0}", e.CommandArgument);
        string url = String.Format("PMUserList?user_id={0}", e.CommandArgument);
        Response.Redirect("UserEdit.aspx");
    }
```

*UserEdit.aspx.cs*

```
     private void LoadData()
        {
            string userid = Session["userid"].ToString();*/
            string Query = "SELECT user_id, name, contact_no,email,role FROM mydb.User WHERE  user_id = " + userid + ";";
            .....}
```

Error message (It is able to select '15001' but passing '?15001' ):

```
{"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?user_id=15001' at line 1"}
```

Please help me improve the session variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your session variable is storing the query string instead of just the user I'd, so your SQL query is invalid. Either just store userid in btn_command or get just the user I'd from session variable in load data and make SQL query

Comment: Change String.Format("PMUserList?user_id={0}",e.CommandArgument) to String.Format("{0}",e.CommandArgument);

Comment: Thank you so much!